# Search a list for a duplicate in Python

Tags: python

```
newWord = print(input('Enter a word: '))
myList = ["apple", "mango"]

def ifWordAlreadyExists(str):
    for x in myList:
        if x == str:
            index = index(x)
            query = print(input('Word ', x ,'is already in index ', index , 'are you sure you want to include it? '))
            if query == 'y':
                return str
            else:
                return 0
myList.append(ifWordAlreadyExists(newWord))
print(myList)
```

Output

```
Enter a word: apple
apple
['apple', 'mango', None]
```

Why is *query* not showing and newWord not appending to myList?
PS. I'm a beginner in Python so I would appreciate if someone could point put what I'm doing wrong :))

Comment: You should change your variable name from str as this is literally the string function. E.g. `str(1)` returns the string `"1"`

Comment: What were you expecting `x == str` to do? Also what is `index`? it's not defined and you are calling it. The function is appending `None` because no `return` statement is reached

Comment: @Countour-Integral i want to compare newWord to x and if they are equal, show query

Comment: print return None Type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `print()` returns `None` and you don't need to place  `input()` method in `print()` because `input()` can also print something to the screen but accept an input.
You can change the code to:

```py
myList = ["apple", "mango"]
newWord = input('Enter a word: ')
check = newWord in myList
if not check:
    myList.append(newWord)
else:
    print('Word', newWord ,'is already on the list are you sure you want to include it?', end=" ")
    query = input().lower().startswith('y')
    if query:
        myList.append(newWord)
print(myList)
```

Output

```
Enter a word: apple
Word apple is already on the list are you sure you want to include it? yes
['apple', 'mango', 'apple']
```

Comment: Could also add the [`myList.index(newWord)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list%20index#common-sequence-operations) feature from question.

Comment: @Jasmijn Please kindly analyse the conditional statement again and you will understand. How you place True or False into conditional statement does not matter as long as your code is readable and easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks for changing it, I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 0):

The **print** function does not return any values

If you want to print the entered value, you must use print on the **bottom line**.

```
newWord = input("Word:")
print(newWord) #like this
myList = ["apple", "mango"]

def ifWordAlreadyExists(str):
    for x in myList:
        if x == str:
            index = myList.index(x)
            query = input("Word {0} is already in index {1} are you sure you want to include it:".format(str,index))
            if query == 'y':
                return str
            else:
                return 0
myList.append(ifWordAlreadyExists(newWord))
print(myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

`newWord` is `None` if you use `newWord = print(input('Enter a word: '))`, it should be `newWord = input('Enter a word: ')`. Besides, you don't have to use a for loop inside the function, the method `index` of a python list can solve it directly, for example

```
newWord = input('Enter a word: ')
myList = ["apple", "mango"]

def ifWordAlreadyExists(to_check):

    try:
        idx = myList.index(to_check)
        query = input('%s is already in the list, are you sure you want to include it? ' % to_check)
        if query == 'y': return to_check
        return 0
    except ValueError:
        return to_check
    
myList.append(ifWordAlreadyExists(newWord))
print(myList)
```

Comment: What happens if user answers with `'n'`? Will `return 0` then add 0 to the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `count()` to find duplicates in a list.

```
def check_duplicates(lst: list):
    for item in lst:
        
        if lst.count(item) > 1:
            return item
        else:
            return "No Duplicates!"
```